# with ser2net package on telnet session arrow keys not working

Tags: bash, shell, serial-port, kernel, console-application

I installed ser2net package in my PC,i started application to read ttyS0 port.
On telnet session things worked fine,except specail keys like arrow and home keys.

Also am not able to edit the file on telnet session.Same thing happened when i used termnetd package also.Is this problem with termios settings ? I tried in many ways by setting termios settings,couldnt get result.

Let me know is there any package needs to added along with ser2net.